# Chain a variable amount of async callback with Vertx.io

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm practicing with vertx.io and I'm reactive noob. In my scenario I have to do a `n` number of operation and collect results together to complete my duty:

```
public void doSomething(String[] params, Handler<AsyncResult<List<Stuff>>> h) {
  for(int i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    doSomethingElse(params[i], hElse -> {
      // compose the list of Stuff
      ... 
    });
  }
}
```

I want to collect results from each `doSomethingElse` method before complete `doSomething`. What is this the right way to accomplish that? Should I change my code to use `vertx.io`'s Future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a RX in your project, no need to bring it. 
You can solve that with CompositeFuture:

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
futures.add(/* Your Futures here */);
CompositeFuture.all(futures);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done in `rx`. Just make sure `doSomethingElse` returns `Single`. You can also replace `Single` with `Observable` if you have multiple data.

```
public void doSomething(String[] params, Handler<AsyncResult<List<Stuff>>> h) {
    List<Single<String>> list = new ArrayList();
  for(int i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
        list.push(doSomethingElse(params[i]))
  }
    Single.zip(list, r -> r)
    .map(results -> {
        // Results
    })
    .subscribe();
}

public Single<String> doSomethingElse(String param){
    return Single.just("Hello");
}
```